# Scrollbars being hidden by other elements in my programme, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is the code I am using to create a scrollable region. However, if I have widgets that extend the visible window (like a frame containing other elements, and which I have to place bellow this code otherwise I can't access the frame built onto the canvas), they cover the scrollbars, preventing me from scrolling. Is there a way that I can prevent this from happening, like being able to always bring the scrollbars to the front?

```
self.canvas1 = Canvas(self, width=1280, height=750, scrollregion=(0,0,2000,700))
self.horizontalscroll = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
self.horizontalscroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
self.horizontalscroll.config(command=self.canvas1.xview)
self.verticalscroll = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
self.verticalscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
self.verticalscroll.config(command=self.canvas1.yview)
self.canvas1.config(xscrollcommand=self.horizontalscroll.set, yscrollcommand=self.verticalscroll.set)
self.canvas1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
self.frame1 = Frame(self)
self.MainWindowSimple = self.canvas1.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame1, anchor='nw')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw your widgets before drawing the scrollbar. Usually, `pack` draws the widget onto the screen/interface. You can use `pack` for scrollbar when you have packed your other widgets.